# How do I split time in a calendar object into hours and minutes to pass in a Bundle?

Tags: android, split, calendar, android-timepicker

I am trying to pass the hour and minutes in a calendar object to a TimePickerFragment.  Android Studio is giving me the following error message on the "tcal.set..." line:  "Must be one of CALENDAR:...HOUR_OF_DAY, MINUTE..."  I have get() statements for "HOUR_OF_DAY and MINUTE" in the Bundle.  Any ideas on why I'm getting this error and how to fix?

```
public class CardViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   private EditText gEditText;

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view);

    gEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.GEditText);
    }
    ...  
    Calendar tcal = Calendar.getInstance();
    String timeStr = gEditText.getText().toString().replace(" ", "");
    String[]timeParts = timeStr.split(":");
    **tcal.set(Integer.parseInt(timeParts[0]),Integer.parseInt(timeParts[1]));**
    Bundle timebundle = new Bundle();
    timebundle.putInt("hour", tcal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    timebundle.putInt("minute", tcal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

This worked perfectly for splitting year, month and day for a DatePicker:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
String dateStr = fListenerEditText.getText().toString().replace(" ","");
String[]dateParts = dateStr.split("/");
c.set(Integer.parseInt(dateParts[2]),Integer.parseInt(dateParts[0])-1,Integer.parseInt(dateParts[1]));
Bundle argsbundle = new Bundle();
argsbundle.putInt("year", c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
argsbundle.putInt("month", c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
argsbundle.putInt("day", c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int%29),

```
public void set(int field, int value)
```

sets the field to the given value.

eg.

```
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 10);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 29);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 22);
calender.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1997);
```

As far as I can see, you are not passing a valid first argument, the field, and thus the error.

This is different from the one with 3 arguments which sets the values for the calendar fields YEAR, MONTH, and DAY_OF_MONTH.

Thus if you use

```
calender.set(2000, 1, 30)
```

, it will set year to 2000, month to January and day to 30th.

But calender.set(int field, int value) has a different use. If you do

```
calender.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1997);
```

It would set year to 1997. Thus the two methods except different arguments and work differently. I hope you get it now :)

Comment: Interesting, I set up a Calendar object previously for year, month and day_of_month and worked perfectly without the int value...see above edit.  Any thoughts?

Comment: If you look at the docs there are three .set functions. But the one with two arguments doesn't work the way the other two work. Please see this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int%29

Comment: Also if the answer cleared your doubt then please accept it :)

Comment: I don't understand the difference betweeen the three .set functions.

Doesn't the below work just like my Year, Month and Day_Of_Month code?

public final void set(int year,
                      int month,
                      int date,
                      int hourOfDay,
                      int minute)

Comment: Ok, so I am trying to split the current time from the Calednar object into two parts. The first part is to put the hour into the TimePicker and the second part is to put the minutes into the TimePicker.  Is this what I need: tcal.set(HOUR, Integer.parseInt(timeParts[0]), MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(timeParts[1])); ?

Comment: No, this would take the form cal.set(int,int,int,int) there is no such function. You have to do it in two steps. tcal.set(Calender.HOUR, Integer.parseInt...) and then tcal.set(Calender.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt...).

Comment: Ok, so because I don't need day, month and year then I need to set in two steps and that requires I use the two field names rather than just int.  Correct?

Comment: Yes Calender.HOUR and Calender.MINUTE are fields and so you have to use exactly the same terms for setting the values.

Comment: Ok, I think I've got it know...thanks for sticking with me, I'm new to Java and Android.  Accepted and upvoted.

Comment: No problem, I was once new too :)